# ConcurrentModificationException in log4j2 ParameterFormatter.appendCollection, when I am increasing load on tomcat

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I am getting CME when I use apache benchmark to send 200000 request with 1000 concurent client, but if keep these values low it works fine.Below is stack trace:

```
2016-07-11 21:02:26,829 http-bio-8080-exec-284 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender debug-log java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.appendCollection(ParameterFormatter.java:575)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.appendPotentiallyRecursiveValue(ParameterFormatter.java:483)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.recursiveDeepToString(ParameterFormatter.java:429)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.formatMessage2(ParameterFormatter.java:189)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessage.formatTo(ParameterizedMessage.java:217)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.MessagePatternConverter.format(MessagePatternConverter.java:65)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:38)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:288)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toText(PatternLayout.java:194)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:180)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:57)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:120)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:113)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:104)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:86)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:155)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:128)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:119)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:390)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:375)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:359)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:349)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2025)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1898)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.debug(Log4jLogger.java:129)
```

Edit: I am using log4j2 2.6

Comment: What version of Log4j are you using? It doesn't match the latest release so it would be helpful if you could try with that. For what it is worth, I am not really sure why your question was downvoted.

Comment: Agreed that the downvote doesn't make sense. Upvoted back to zero. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are logging a Collection which is being modified while the Log4j 2 `ParameterFormatter` is iterating over its elements to create a text representation.

From the stacktrace, Log4j 2 is configured to log synchronously so perhaps the Collection is modified by another thread than the application thread that is logging.

Another thing about synchronous logging is that your benchmark results may simply reflect the cost of the disk I/O, or, if your benchmark is multithreaded, the cost of lock contention in the Log4j 2 appender. This may well be the dominant cost. If this is what you want to measure then great. Otherwise I'd strongly recommend using Log4j 2's [Async Loggers](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html). The simplest way to use Async Loggers involves setting a single system property: set `Log4jContextSelector` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector`.

Comment: In async logger since it takes snapshot, is snapshot like making some kind of defensive copy,. If yes, will using it trigger gc more offen?

Comment: Async Loggers cannot take a defensive copy of the parameter objects, so instead the message is rendered to text before it is passed to the background thread. Since 2.6, Log4j tries to be garbage-free, but calling ArrayList.toString() will create temporary objects. (This is the same for both synchronous and asynchronous logging.)

Comment: From a GC point of view, async logging and synchronous logging are pretty much the same. The difference is that Async Loggers avoid lock contention and I/O in the application thread. That is where the performance benefits come from.

Comment: Hmm but in scenraio of custom layouts will they be called by background thread or app thread,

Comment: My question who will call layout configured since message is formatted before passing to aync logger

Comment: The message may be formatted but the LogEvent also has a time stamp, thread name, logger name, level etc that also may need to be written out for each event. Each Appender calls its Layout to take care of that.